# Save django charfield with spaces replaced on model save

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a `CharField` to another `CharField` on model save in django. I've done the following:

```
class Mall(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    raw_name = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=300) #to prevent from appearing in admin

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.raw_name = self.name.replace(" ", "_")
        super(Mall, self).save()
```

However, this isn't working and it saves as an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ["Overriding predefined model methods"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) paragraph:

> It’s also important that you pass through the arguments that can be
>   passed to the model method – that’s what the *args, **kwargs bit does.
>   Django will, from time to time, extend the capabilities of built-in
>   model methods, adding new arguments. If you use *args, **kwargs in
>   your method definitions, you are guaranteed that your code will
>   automatically support those arguments when they are added.

In other words, you need to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` along:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.raw_name = self.name.replace(" ", "_")
    super(Mall, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the raw_name be a SlugField.  Especially useful with [prepopulated fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields)